# Defaulting to PM instead of AM when not adding "AM/PM" to the end of a time formatted cell

Tags: excel, datetime

**Edit**: I have since learned that this is only possible with formulas that add 12 hours to the time.

I have a "Time out" column in my Excel timesheet and I would like it to default to PM when I forget to add "PM" manually. I just by habit don't put in PM and it defaults to AM which messes up my formula I have for the "Hours:" column which calculates the difference between the time out and the time in which gets the hours I worked for the day. I was hoping for a way to make it default to PM in the formatting to avoid using extra formulas or complications.

[image]

Comment: you change the custom number format to something like `h:mm "PM"`, but the time will be still in am

Comment: AM and PM are still important to the formulas so I don't want it to just display as PM but actually register as PM or greater than 12:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it, but maybe you could add a custom format adding 12 hrs to the given time. Alternatively you could add a column (width 0 pt) for calculating the working hours that is adding these 12 hrs?

Comment: After looking into it this is the best possible answer, thank you.